# Android, Adapter adding extra element to array?

Tags: java, android

I have an adapter that create 16 buttons in a gradview, as the buttons are being created im give then a tag and add it to an array, for some reason when i print the log it shows me 17 elements...any ideas why it contains 17 elements when i create 16 buttons...

```
public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> colorsArray = new ArrayList<String>(0);// add button tags

    public ButtonAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        int a = 16;// HOW MANY TILES WILL THE ADAPTER DISPLAY AND CREATE IN
                    // THE GRID VIEW, REFRENCED IN THE onCreate METHOD BELOW
        return a;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Button button;
        if (convertView == null) {
            int r = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 5);

            button = new Button(mContext);
            button.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            button.setText("" + r);// set text to random number

            // give each button a new reference number
            int r4 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 5);
            int r3 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 4);
            int r2 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 3);
            int r1 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 2);

            // setup attributes for each button
            if (r == 5) {

                button.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
                button.setText("" + r4);// set text to new random number
                colorsArray.add("yellow");
                button.setTag("yellow");


            } else if (r == 4) {

                button.setBackgroundColor(green);
                button.setText("" + r3);
                colorsArray.add("green");
                button.setTag("green");

            } else if (r == 3) {

                button.setBackgroundColor(red);
                button.setText("" + r2);
                colorsArray.add("red");
                button.setTag("red");

            } else if (r == 2) {

                button.setBackgroundColor(blue);
                button.setText("" + r1);
                colorsArray.add("blue");
                button.setTag("blue");

            } else if (r == 1) {

                button.setBackgroundColor(purple);
                colorsArray.add("purple");
                button.setTag("purple");

            } else {

                button.setBackgroundColor(white);
                button.setText("0");

            }

            Log.d(TAG, colorsArray.toString());

        } else {
            button = (Button) convertView;

        }
        return button;
```

Comment: where did you print your log stating there is 17 items?

Comment: The botton of the getView method of the adapter i have..Log.d(TAG, colorsArray.toString());

Comment: Judging from the codes I could not determine where's the fault yet, you may include position together in your Log to get a better debug output.

Comment: In `getItemId` replace `return 0` by `return position;`.

Comment: Is there somthing about adapters im missing??? @vorrtex, When i change the getItemId return to position, the array has only 13 items in the log...???Such a head scratcher!!!

Comment: @ronanc You add items to your array only if `convertView == null`, but android tries to reuse views and the convertView parameter is not empty. Add the `Log.d` call to the else clause to verify this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...the log from the else block..05-02 22:23:16.965: D/GameScreen(2077): array:[blue, blue, red, purple, red, green, purple, red, blue, red, green, blue, red, green, purple, blue, blue]...17 elements...contextView log from the else shows me...05-02 22:23:16.944: D/GameScreen(2077): else array......:[blue]...??how can i correct this???

Comment: If you run the application - there will be exactly 16 squares on the UI. You have a different number of elements in your array because the convertView parameter is often not null and `colorsArray.add` is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of the issue: GridView always creates 1 extra view, no matter whether all views are visible or not.

Example when all 16 views are visible:
[image]

At first it created and displayed 16 views (the last view is red 1). Then it created 1 extra view (view 17, red 2) which will never be displayed.

I don't know why GridView does this. Someone from the Android team decided to implement this control in such vague way.

As to your adapter, I would suggest that you populate your `colorsArray` in the constructor and don't change it in other places. Than you will be sure that it contains no more than 16 items.

Comment: Hi vorrtex...big thanks for such an in-dept reply:)...now i now much more about adapters...I have moved the coloArray into the constructor but it still reads 17 elements....i think i just might have to colorsArray.remove(colorsArray.size()-1); after the adapter has run

Comment: @ronanc You should have changed methods getView and getCount as well so that they call `colorsArray.get(position)` and `colorsArray.getCount()` accordingly. And after that the adapter can read as much elements as it needs, colorsArray will remain the same.